# Change Android IP address using application

Tags: java, android, ip, runtime.exec

I am trying to change the ip address inside my application for emulator or a device

This the code:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","ifconfig eth0 xx.xx.xx.xx"});
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No exception caught but sill the ip address is not changed!
any one know why?

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, ifconfig on Android has very limited functionalities and most people suggest to use netcfg instead.

Comment: I have tried it with netcfg but it's the same, ip not changed